# Clone two elements and store them in one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says is there a way I can clone two elements and store them in one variable instead of creating a separate variable. Tried using `&&` to get both elements but didn't work

```js
var menu = $('a[href$="/items"]').clone() && $('a[href$="/items"]').next().clone();

$('.footer .footer-menu').append(menu);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="aim/items">Item </a>
      <ul>
          <li>item one</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="footer">
    this is a footer
    <div class="footer-menu">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the `.add()` method, or just call `.append()` twice, once for each clone, and then you don't need the variable at all. Or select both elements first and then call `.clone()` only once.

Comment: Is your main concern about storing it one variable or is it that you want to use `append` only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with an `array` solution https://jsfiddle.net/wrdp548d/

```js
var menu = [];
menu.push($('a[href$="/items"]').clone());
menu.push($('a[href$="/items"]').next().clone());

$('.footer .footer-menu').append(menu);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="aim/items">Item </a>
      <ul>
          <li>item one</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="footer">
    this is a footer
    <div class="footer-menu">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

**Another way**

```js
var menu = [];
menu.push($('a[href$="/items"]').clone());
menu.push($('a[href$="/items"]').next().clone());


$.each(menu, function(i){
 $('.footer .footer-menu').append(menu[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="aim/items">Item </a>
      <ul>
          <li>item one</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="footer">
    this is a footer
    <div class="footer-menu">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you go with an object solution https://jsfiddle.net/wrdp548d/1/

```js
var menu = {
 clone1: $('a[href$="/items"]').clone(),
  clone2: $('a[href$="/items"]').next().clone()
};


for(var key in menu){
  $('.footer .footer-menu').append(menu[key]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="aim/items">Item </a>
      <ul>
          <li>item one</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="footer">
    this is a footer
    <div class="footer-menu">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: *"Here you go with an JSON solution"* - That's not JSON, it's an object.

Comment: No, just an object. [There's no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Ok... Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple variable can only hold one value. If you need to hold more than one you either use an array or object.

Using array:

```
var clone1 = $('a[href$="/items"]').clone();
var clone2 = $('a[href$="/items"]').next().clone();

var menu = [clone1, clone2];
```

or object:

```
 var clone1 = $('a[href$="/items"]').clone();
 var clone2 = $('a[href$="/items"]').next().clone();

 var menu = {'clone1': clone1, 'clone2': clone2};
```

Then you're going to have to access the values by looping thru it or directly accessing it via array index `menu[0]` or object properties `menu.clone1` `menu[clone1]`